TopAppBar has unknown padding when using nested Scaffold with Compose Navigation
I have a Scaffold at the root level of app where I host the navigation. This scaffold doesn't have a top app bar and only contains a FAB. Then, in one of the destinations, I am using another Scaffold which does have a top app bar.
Now, when go to that destination the top app bar is having some unknown/extra padding on top. I didn't specify any extra padding to it using Modifier. The following screenshot shows it:

As you can see above Medicines, we have some extra padding which is unexpected. How can I solve this problem? Does it have anything to do with nested Scaffolds and whether it is recommended to do so or not?

You should make the Scaffold part of each screen instead of having it at the root level. This gives you more control over how each screen looks and behaves. If a screen doesn't need a Scaffold, you can omit it.
Something similar to this:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            NavLearnTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()

                NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "top") {
                    composable("top") { TopScreen( /* ... */ ) }
                    composable("another") { AnotherScreen( /* ... */ ) }
                    // Add more destinations similarly.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TopScreen() {
    Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton = { /* fab code here */ },
        // other content
    ) { innerPadding ->
        // content here
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun AnotherScreen() {
    Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton = { /* fab code here */ },
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(title = { /*TODO*/ })
        }
        // other content
    ) { innerPadding ->
        // content here
    }
}


I haven't used Jetpack Compose in the past. In Views, we used to have a single MainActivity with a single app bar. So, I thought we could use a Scaffold at the top level just like Views. When I use a Scaffold inside Scaffold without NavHost, the extra padding is not visible. I would like to know why this is happening with NavHosts.

It's okay to do that in compose. You didn't share any code, so I can't say why you're seeing the extra padding.

I still don't know the reason behind the extra padding but I solved the problem in the following way.

I took a top level Scaffold just like the JetNews sample app which has just a FAB. I also ignored the PaddingValues.

Inside this Scaffold, I put my NavHost and within it the different screens.

Each screen had its own Scaffold which contained a top app bar and it also utilized the PaddingValues to account for the top app bar.


Now, the problem was that as I didn't used the PaddingValues in the app level Scaffold, the NavHost was taking full width across the status bar and the navigation bar as I had called enableEdgeToEdge.
So, I solved it by considering the status bar's padding as mentioned in the sample app i.e. applying the padding on the top app bar using Modifier.statusBarsPadding().
I don't know the exact reason for the extra padding, but most probably it had something to do with the PaddingValues inside the content composable function of Scaffold. In my original code, I utitlized them in both the top level Scaffold as well as on the screen level ones. Maybe due to that, the inner level Scaffold consumed the insets/padding of the top level one. Please correct me if I am wrong. 
